Sleep doesn't work on Kubuntu 22.04 with my Lenovo ThinkBook-14-G6-AHP (it powers off instead)
I am stuck with Ubuntu 22.04, but I want to install 6.11 kernel for my laptop to go to sleep normally. Is it possible?
I tried changing system settings in Power Management, as well as editing the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file to uncomment the HandleLidSwitch=suspend line.
However, when I close the lid of my laptop it just powers off instead of going to sleep.
The command, cat /sys/power/mem_sleep, shows only one thing:
[s2idle]

The laptop is equipped with a Ryzen 7 8745H (basically a 8845H without the AI stuff).
I suspect it is a kernel issue, because I tried using Nobara Linux before switching to Ubuntu due to the fact that I can't get Davinci Resolve working in Nobara. And with Nobara's 6.11 kernel the laptop would go to sleep normally, no problem at all.
So I am trying to install 6.11 kernel on my Ubuntu 22.04, but the mainline kernel can't be installed because of some dependency issues. Only possible with Ubuntu 24.04, but I can't use 24.04 again because of Davinci Resolve. For some reason ROCM refused to work on Ubuntu 24.04, so I can't get Davinci Resolve's timeline to output anything. I also tried Davincibox, which uses distrobox and rusticl, and it does make Davinci Resolve function normally but the performance is far far far worse than ROCM.
I tried compiling the kernel myself but encountered an error that stops the compilation.
dpkg-buildpackage: error: make -f debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2

I really had no idea what I was doing, so I just gave up on the idea of compiling kernel myself.
EDIT:

Sleep works when I click sleep in KDE's start menu, but once I close the lid, it powers off, even during sleep.

I set the laptop to sleep only when on battery mode, and on AC power when I close the lid it only locks the screen. So when I close the lid with AC power, the laptop locks the screen, and then if I unplug the cable, the laptop powers off immediately.

It's not 100% happening. There was one or two times the laptop DID go to sleep, but 99% of the time it just powers off when the lid is closed.


